# Pre-Colonial Population Density in the Americas

Tags: data-request

Any data that estimates pre-colonial population density in the Americas (especially, S. America)?

Comment: Maybe worth checking the sources in Acemoglu et al. (2002) [Reversal of Fortune](http://economics.mit.edu/files/4127)? They do use urbanization data, including some South American countries. I don't know of any specific source for population density.